# How to read 16 bit parallel data using external adc output in stm32

Tags: stm32

I facing trouble in reading 16 bit parallel data continuously using external adc output in my stm32f4

Im using
GPIOA->IDR
How is 16 bit data stored in IDR
and how to access the input data regiter continuously for every sample

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> How is 16 bit data stored in IDR

GPIOx_IDR is not a *latch*, so data are not *stored* in it. Each time you read GPIOx_IDR by processor or by DMA, it returns the current state of given port's pins.

The ADC (what model?) most probably has a pin using which you start conversion, and another pin which indicates back that conversion has been completed.

The first version of your software should toggle the start-conversion pin, and then in loop wait until conversion-ready pin gets active, and then read GPIOx_IDR to determine the conversion result.

Later on, you can "automate" this process by triggering the conversion periodically using timer, and DMA to read the result, triggered from conversion-ready through a different timer channel (as input capture); for that, read the TIM and DMA chapters in RM0090.